# Compiling Android Bootloader Little Kernel

Tags: bootloader, aosp

I have successfully compiled Android bootloader from git://codeaurora.org/kernel/lk.git

It produces a lk.bin file which I assume is the code for the bootloader.

How do I pack that file into a bootloader.img file for fastboot flashing?

Comment: what other tools can I use other than fastboot?

Comment: It's a Qualcomm chipset.

Comment: QPST, MiFlash, MSMDownloadTool or similar tool for [EDL](https://github.com/bkerler/edl) mode

Comment: Thanks. I tried all those tools and after reading articles about Qualcomm secure boot, I don't think it's possible to write  your own bootloader once the oem enables it.